# How to pass value of datetimepicker to another datetimepicker in another form

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have a datetimepicker values in datagridview. (Arrival date and departure date)
Here is screen shoot.
[image: Screenshot 1]

Also, I have an edit form for the values in datagrid view.

[image]

How can I pass the values of datetimepicker from datagridview to the second form as datetimepicker value.

Here is my try:

```
  private void arrivaldgv_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            edit edt = new edit();
            edt.label12.Text = this.label2.Text;
            edt.label13.Text = this.arrivaldgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            edt.textBox1.Text = this.arrivaldgv.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            edt.textBox2.Text = this.arrivaldgv.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            edt.textBox3.Text = this.arrivaldgv.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
         /*   edt.dateTimePicker1.Value = this.arrivaldgv.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value;   problem here */
            edt.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `System.Convert.ToDateTime` method:

```
edt.dateTimePicker1.Value = System.Convert.ToDateTime(this.arrivaldgv.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
```

Comment: sure, in 5 min :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime.Parse` method:

```
edt.dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(this.arrivaldgv.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
```

Most of the `.ToX` methods use some instance methods internally, such is the case here too, which means that this should work faster than `Convert.ToDateTime()`